# Ubuntu server 12.04 what is it

Tags: server

Know I now what a server is, at school we used to mess with red-hat(2003?).
mostly just do exactly what the teacher/textbook tells u to.(didn't learn allot)
But newer really knew what a server could do.

My question is What is Ubuntu server 12.04
And what can u do with it

Comment: The 'what can you do with it' part of your question is overly broad, can you state a more specific goal?

Comment: I don't really fully understand the concept of a server. 
I know u can use it as a file/web server but don't really know how those works?
my goal to learn is everything. Web server how does that works. File server how does that works. Sorry if i am asking a lot.
i am an it-student and the more knowledge i have about it the better :)

Comment: Then your question is really 'What is a server?', and as such it is off-topic for Ask Ubuntu and should be closed. To make sure you still get an answer for your question, [here's a good starting point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_%28computing%29), it's Wikipedia's page explaining what a server is. Good luck in your studies.

Comment: Thanks. But that explains about "*servers" although in my comment i said nothing about "Ubuntu server" (sorry) but my question is how does "Ubuntu server" work and it's features and such apologize for any inconvenience.

Comment: No worries, I want to make sure you get a good answer somewhere. Are you wanting to know how Ubuntu Server differs from say Windows Server or something like that? A comparison of different server OSs?

Comment: Yes, That would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Server and Desktop Differences**

There are a few differences between the *Ubuntu Server Edition* and the *Ubuntu Desktop Edition*. It should be noted that both editions use the same apt repositories, making it just as easy to install a server application on the Desktop Edition as it is on the Server Edition.

The differences between the two editions are the lack of an *X window environment* in the Server Edition, the installation process, and different Kernel options.

**Package Tasks**

During the Server Edition installation you have the option of installing additional packages from the CD. The packages are grouped by the type of service they provide.

```
DNS server: Selects the BIND DNS server and its documentation.

LAMP server: Selects a ready-made Linux/Apache/MySQL/PHP server.

Mail server: This task selects a variety of packages useful for a general purpose mail server system.

OpenSSH server: Selects packages needed for an OpenSSH server.

PostgreSQL database: This task selects client and server packages for the PostgreSQL database.

Print server: This task sets up your system to be a print server.

Samba File server: This task sets up your system to be a Samba file server, which is especially suitable in networks with both Windows and Linux systems.

Tomcat Java server: Installs Apache Tomcat and needed dependencies.

Virtual Machine host: Includes packages needed to run KVM virtual machines.

Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP) : is a network service that enables host computers to be automatically assigned settings from a server as opposed to manually configuring each network host.
```

Source and If you would like to get more information look this [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Basically Ubuntu desktop edition comes with a set of preinstalled software and in particular graphical interfaces (i.e if you boot Ubuntu server you will get a console and not a graphical login screen).

To reduce the load on servers, potential security risks, etc. the server edition comes with a reduce set of preinstalled software. The install process will also ask if you want to install specific services such as web server, mail server and so on. Additional technical differents exist such as different kernel parameters (the core software allowing your computer to work).

On the opposite, except the initial configuration both systems can install the same packages using the Ubuntu package manager so with some effort you can mimic the Ubuntu behavior on a desktop install or the opposite.

See the Ubuntu server edition manual [for more information](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/preparing-to-install.html#intro-server-differences).